# What is a compile time constant expression in Java?

Tags: java, constants, compile-time-constant

I have read that final variables in Java should be instantiated to compile time constant expression. I couldn't understand what is compile time constant expression.

```
class A {
    int i;
    int j  = i * 5;
}
```

Is `i * 5 a compile time constant expression?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Answer (score 1):

A "compile time constant expression" is a value that can be calculated during compilation. For example, `int MINUTES_IN_DAY = 24 * 60;`

As for your reading that final variables should always be instantiated in that form: that's an incorrect generalisation. There are many instances where you need a `final` to be evaluable at runtime, such as when setting up `Runnable`s.

Note that static final variables do not need to be compile-time constants either: you can initialise them using *static initialisers*.

Comment: is it necessary that static final variables should be compiled time constants ?